# How can I monitor whether disk activity is sychronous or asynchronous?

Tags: io, zfs, top, write, iostat

My Google-fu simply cannot find an answer to this.

If I have a process with heavy I/O activity, how can I check whether it's using asynchronous or synchronous writes?

(I want this information to decide whether to add a SLOG to my ZFS pool.)

Comment: (Of course, the workaround solution is just to add a SLOG and see whether it's used. Hoping for a more direct way to monitor.)

Comment: Do your applications run fsync a lot? e.g. a database like postgresql or mysql?  if so, then a SLOG might help.   If you have a spare drive slot, try installing the smallest, fastest SSD you can find and using that as SLOG (ideally, you'd have two such devices, mirrored, because a single-drive SLOG is a single-point-of-failure).

Comment: BTW, unless you're writing an enormous amount of synchronous data, you won't need much space.  a 4GB partition (or mirrored pair of 4GB partitions) would be far more than you'll ever use...my slog mirror devices are 4GB and I've never seen it use more than 1MB or so.   I don't really need them, but I had some spare space for SLOG partitions on some SSDs that I didn't need for anything else.

Comment: That's exactly the point: I don't know what my applications run, I would expect there to be an iostat-type way of checking that rather than having to dig into the applications' details.

Comment: I slapped in just a 1GB SLOG while doing a `zfs receive` from another pool, and it *appeared* to greatly increase the throughput (~3x speedup). But no one ever mentions `zfs receive` when talking about sync writes, so perhaps it was a coincidence.

Comment: See if the `zpool iostat -q <pool>` provides the info you want. It includes the sync and async queue depths in the stats. That could give you an idea of proportions.

Comment: But does this mean that there is no general solution to monitor all disk activity (a la iotop) with knowledge of what is synchronous/asynchronous?